# pass javascript function to child window opened with window.open()

Tags: javascript, function, popup

Having problems passing a javascript function from parent window to child window. Works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE (tested with IE11). Ironically it works even in IE if F12 dev tools are opened. This is in the same domain so cross domain blocks should no be an issue. What I have tried:

```
// on the parent
var newWin = window.open('href', 'title', ''); 
newWin.myFunc = function() { alert('test'); };

// on the child (when calling this I get error: 'myFunc' is undefined)
myFunc();
```

I know I can go the other way around -- calling a function defined on the parent from the child:

```
// on the parent
function myFunc() {
    alert('test');
}

// from child
opener.myFunc();
```

But for reasons beyond the scope of this questions I need to be able to pass an anonymous function to the child which it must to be able to execute.

Comment: Does the function you’re testing call `alert`, or does it do something else and also use `console.log`? `console` doesn’t exist in IE until the console is open, so `console.log` will throw an error and stop anything else from happening, depending on where you have it.

Comment: The actual function does not call alert() nor console.log. It does some data manipulation that is not in any way related to UI.

Comment: Shot in the dark here,  you try window.parent.myFunc(); yet?

Comment: That does not meet the requirement I have which is having the ability to pass anonymous functions to the child. Of course as stated above if you declare the function in the parent you can call it from the child. But I need to not declare the function in the parent and instead pass an anonymous function to the child to execute.

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of trying all kinds of things, I ended up with this solution:

```
// on parent
var newWin = window.open('href', 'title', ''); 
$(newWin.document).ready(function() {
    newWin.myFunc = function() {
        alert('test');
    };
});

// on the child
myFunc();
```

Again Chrome and Firefox seem to allow variable declarations on the child window immediately before the document is loaded so this workaround is not needed for them but this will work just as well.

Comment: This doesn't really work consistently though. Fails with an "access denied" error if window is opened in fast succession with the same window name. Both Firefox and IE error out. I guess there is no way to pass anonymous functions to child windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I used `setTimout()` function to fix an undefined function called error in the child window. I hope this will work in all

```js
//Add this to the page loads on the child browser window.
browsers.
setTimeout(function(){
  window.opener.FunctionName(param1,param2);
},1000);
```